# Get row count using two columns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
         ID                DBA BUILDING     STREET   SCORE GRADE GRADE DATE
0  50054472  LE PAIN QUOTIDIEN      395  S END AVE       9     A 2016-10-13
```

I want to get the count of rows that satisfy a given criterion as I loop over the rows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(CSV_URL, parse_dates=['GRADE DATE'], keep_default_na=False)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df[(df['ID'] == row[0]) & df['GRADE DATE'] == pd.Timestamp(row[6])]
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [bool]
```

I understand that I am getting a `Timestamp` object using the `parse_dates` so that is why I am converting it to a `pd.Timestamp` before the query. Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: You have a single `&` where perhaps you would like `and`?

Comment: df[(df['ID'] == row[0]) & df['GRADE DATE'] == pd.Timestamp(row[6])].shape

Comment: df[your conditions].shape

Comment: please post a sample df and expected df

Comment: Add parentheses around `df['GRADE DATE'] == pd.Timestamp(row[6])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments are correct that `df[(df['ID'] == row[0]) & df['GRADE DATE'] == pd.Timestamp(row[6])]` looks like it needs to be edited at least to: `df[(df['ID'] == row[0]) & (df['GRADE DATE'] == pd.Timestamp(row[6]))]`

There is almost always a way for you to avoid using `for` loops with pandas, pandas advises you to avoid `for` loops. Since this appears to be the NYC health inspections dataset...

```
import pandas as pd
CSV_URL = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/43nn-pn8j/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD'
df = pd.read_csv(CSV_URL, parse_dates=['GRADE DATE'], keep_default_na=False)

def id_counter(row):
  return df[(df['CAMIS'] == row[0]) & (df['GRADE DATE'] == row['GRADE DATE'])].shape[0]

df["RESULT"]=df.apply(id_counter, axis=1)
```

This tries to store the amount of violations at ID (CAMIS) on GRADE DATE in RESULT without using a `for` loop. But from having worked with city data before, I would say your mileage may vary.